# Is 'class Node' a java library component?

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I have been asked to implement a doubly linked list without using any java library components. Is 'Node' a java library component? So if I create a class:`private static class Node{ }` is that breaking the rules?

Comment: `Node` is not a Java library component. You certainly can create a class `private static class Node<T> { T value; Node<T> prev; Node<T> next; }`

Comment: This is one of the reasons Java has packages: it provides a namespace for classes, making them unique, even if their simple name is the same as another class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several `Node` classes in Java (for example [`java.util.LinkedList.Node`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17u/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java#L974), [`java.util.HashMap.Node`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17u/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#L281), [`org.w3c.dom.Node`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.xml/org/w3c/dom/Node.html)).

If you create your own class `private static class Node{ }` then it will be your own class which has nothing in common with the various node classes from the java libraries **except** for the simple name (`Node`).

Using a name for a class that happens to be similar to a name that the java libraries use for different classes and purposes is not the same as using the java library components themselves.